# Correct Regex to extract date times out of expression like this

Tags: c#, regex, string, datetime

In short, what I'm trying to do is make the following test succeed

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DateTimeFormatTest()
    {
        string text = "jose23 (11/1/2016 11:27pm, 8 posts)";
        var matches = BoardScanner.DateTimeFormat.Matches(text);
        Assert.AreEqual(matches.Count, 1, String.Format("Couldn't extract date from {0} using DateTimeFormat", text));
        var match = matches[0];
        try
        {
           DateTime.Parse(match.Value);
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Couldn't convert {0} to DateTime object", match.Value);
        }
    }
```

The regex I'm using is

```
new Regex(@"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}/^(am|pm|AM|PM)")
```

and obviously isn't working

Comment: `string dtprt = text.Split('(')[1].ToString().Split(',')[0].ToString();` can also pull your date if pattern will be always same. like if date is always between `(` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because:

- Forward slashes need to be escaped with a backslash in Regex.
- Month and day can be either 1 or 2 digits, but you are explicitly looking for exactly 2 digits in those areas.
- the `^` character represents the start of the string, so in the middle of your pattern it's going to cause your match to fail no matter what you're checking it against (depending on your flags, at least).

The following pattern works for the input you provided:

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}(am|pm|AM|PM)
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to make do a case-insensitive am|pm rather than writing am|pm|AM|PM?

Comment: @DeadlyNicotine You can use the `i` flag to make your Regex search be case insensitive.